# NTFS and Veracrypt VS HFS+ Encrypted?

Tags: encryption, ntfs, hfs+, truecrypt

I want to create a backup disk where I occasionally connect it to my macOS and copy important things manually.

I may also connect this disk to Windows in rare cases.

I also want to encrypt the disk/container.

I accept to lose the ability to use this disk on Windows. (which may occur if I choose HFS+ encrypted)

What is the most reliable and fast way to achieve this?
Using NTFS and Veracrypt?
Using HFS+ Encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

If you format the disk exFAT you will have a disk that is read and writable on both systems. Then on the mac side you can create an encrypted disk image on that drive that is only accessible on a Mac. You can also create an encrypted .zip file on the PC (with 3rd party software) that is only readable on a PC.

Alternatively, if you don't mind partitioning the drive, you can create a drive with one NTFS and one HFS+ partition on it then you can encrypt both at the file system level and each will be accessible only on their corresponding operating system.